# How to disable caching?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, caching

Using chrome 54.0.2840.90 (64-bit), I have weird experience with API calls (using GET), Google Chrome caching many of my API calls, so that after I delete a row for example, and reloading the page, Chrome don't send that request to server, instead serving it from its cache. I already add

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

but chrome still caching API request that I made

Comment: HTTP cache header sent by server have higher weightage than whatever you set using `<meta>` tags so the only way is to change it on the server.But generally API server always provide cache control to avoid caching .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, just like @Novice said in the comment. I need to set cache-control directly to HTML header. Here's what I do (using exppress and node.js)

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
res.json(res.JSONResponce);
```

Reference : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html sub 14.9 Cache-Control